# How can I solve datagrid showing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to add a data table to a datagrid on WPF (C#) but when the columns become more than 29, the datagrid does not show the values of other columns. could anyone help me in this problem?
thank you

```
DtGrResult.ItemsSource = tbl_main.AsDataView();
```

Comment: Is scrolling enabled for `DataGrid` ?

Comment: Please include the xaml for the datagrid and its container

Comment: Yes it seems issue with container.

Comment: <telerik:RadGridView ItemContainerStyle="" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"  Name="DtGrResult" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Extended" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" DataLoadMode="Synchronous" ActionOnLostFocus="CommitEdit" IsFilteringAllowed="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True">                    </telerik:RadGridView>

Answer (score 0):

Set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility attribute of the datagrid to *Visible* or *Auto* and make sure each of your columns' Frozen attribute is set to *false*.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: thanks but it couldn't help me. when I don't use AsdataView() part, everything is OK, but data view it doesn't work.